# Selecionar pasta em diretório no input

Tags: asp.net-mvc

Preciso colocar um `input` onde o usuário selecione a pasta que ele quer que deseje que salve as notas, porém somente selecionar.

Eu tentei fazer desta forma:

```
 <input asp-for="Caminho" class="form-control" type="file" multiple webkitdirectory id="pasta">
```

Porém ele aparece para fazer `upload`
E quando eu faço assim:

```
<input asp-for="Caminho" class="form-control" type="file" id="pasta">
```

Ele aparece para selecionar um arquivo, e não uma pasta.
Tem alguma maneira que eu consiga selecionar a pasta e pegar o caminho ?

**EDIT**

Eu preciso apenas selecionar a pasta, somente para ficar fácil para o usuário, assim ele não precisa digitar o caminho na mão. Alguma maneira de fazer isso?

Comment: Nao consigo dar uma resposta agra... mas veja aqui: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12942436/how-to-get-folder-directory-from-html-input-type-file-or-any-other-way

Comment: @Barbetta desse link que me passou eu tentei, porém ele informa para fazer upload, e não selecionar a pasta. Eu só queria selecionar a pasta, para que o usuário não precise digitar, selecionando desta forma, fica mais dinâmico.

Answer (score 1):

Não é possível selecionar a pasta de um site usando `HTML native` + `JS`. Você só pode selecionar um arquivo ou lista de arquivos para upload, mas não uma pasta em si.

Normalmente você nem vai conseguir ver o caminho original do arquivo que foi carregado, e você simplesmente não pode obter acesso direto ao sistema de arquivos do usuário.

A comunicação da Web é baseada em solicitações `HTTP` e é `stateless`, portanto, não haveria como o servidor acessar a pasta no PC (remoto) do usuário. E por motivos de segurança, nem mesmo o `JavaScript` no cliente pode fazê-lo.

O usuário pode deixar a pasta `downloads`configurada por padrão na maioria dos navegadores de hoje em dia.

Comment: Tem alguma forma de pegar um caminho dinamicamente então ? Pois a pasta será usada em outra função, salvando arquivos, que já funciona, porém queria que esta pasta fosse configurável.

Comment: O arquivo vai ser salvo no próprio servidor onde está rodando a aplicação ou no cliente?

Comment: No próprio ciente.

Comment: Então não. O seu HTML não consegue ter acesso ao computador do cliente

Comment: @marianac_costa entendo que o cliente pode ter pedido, mas se é uma aplicação web o navegador tem o controle de onde o download vai ser salvo e o usuário pode escolher/ configurar como já informei na resposta e como o Victor Laio já informou aqui na dele também. Nesse caso não é melhor alinhar a conversa com o cliente e explicar que há um impedimento técnico e que esse pedido pode deixar a ferramenta insegura ou com bugs?

Answer (score 0):

Isso não é possível com **HTML** ou **Javascript** devido a questões de segurança.

Existem soluções que tentam implementar isso nos navegadores mas que não funcionam bem em todos navegadores, não sendo nem um pouco viável.

Também não vejo muito sentido nisso, pois se você quer "salvar algum arquivo" os navegadores já disponibilizam a pasta download que pode ser configurada pelo usuário.

Comment: Eu só preciso salvar o caminho, para quando for gerar uma NFe ele saiba onde salvar, e para o usuário, fica mais dinâmico. Eu quero apenas salvar o caminho.